# Percentage of values when one column has values and other column is null

Tags: python-3.x

May be this is the duplicate of other question but I am not able to solve the problem.

I have transaction data having 100 features and 2.3 million rows. I want to find percentage of values present in one column and Null in other column for every combination of columns.

Example:

```
  A  B  C  D
  1  NA 2  3
  2  4  5  6
  NA 5  6  7
  8  2  NA NA
  9  8  7  6
```

So output should be:

```
  When A has values B has Null 1/4=0.25 times
  When A has values C has Null 1/4=0.25 times
```

Similarly for every other combination of columns and create a dataframe for it.

I tried combination of columns function in Python but it's not giving the desired result.

```
itertools.combinations(daf.columns, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write 2 for loops to iterate  for individual columns and then compare.